# Android for loop wait for click event counter then continue the loop

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, onclicklistener

Assume i have an array like :

```
Array {
    {
        "id" => 1,
        "text" => "First Text"
    },
    {
        "id" => 2,
        "text" => "Second Text"
    },
    {
        "id" => 3,
        "text" => "Third Text"
    },
}
```

and i want to output the first element of array `text => First Text`

then having a `Button` that i will click and if the click count of this button equals like `4` output the next element of array `text => Second Text` until i reach the end of the array.

By knowing that the array will have dynamic number of elements with different data.

The code i have :

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++)
{
    someElement.setText(i);

    break;
}
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can achive this by writing its code!

Comment: So share your code. Show us what you can't figure out in your code.

Comment: My code is just pretty straight forward self explained for loop on that array! Trying to help? Or just posting some standards?

Answer (score 1):

Make a `private int` in your `Button` class, which saves the current index of the text in the `array`.

On click, the button should do the following

```
if(cur_text_index == array.size())
{ return; }

setText(array.get(cur_text_index));
++cur_text_index;
```

If you want the button to be clicked a couple times before changing its text, add a second `private int` in your `Button` class, which saves the number it has been clicked without changing its text.

On click, the button should do the following

```
if(cur_text_index == array.size())
{ return; }

if(clicks_since_text_change < 4)
{
  ++clicks_since_text_change;
  return;
}
clicks_since_text_change= 0;

setText(array.get(cur_text_index));
++cur_text_index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use ids at all?
Couldn't you just use a Array with the values "first text","second text","third text"
So

> String[] textArray =new String[]{"first text","second text","third text"}
>
> int textIndex=0;

And then say

```
    someElement.setText(textIndex++)
```

In the onClickListener?

To prevent it from accessing an index that doesn't exist you can put an

`if(textIndex+1>=textArray.length)`

around it